# bash: how to change the basename only of a list of files

Tags: bash, rename, prefix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [makefile: how to add a prefix to the basename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322643/makefile-how-to-add-a-prefix-to-the-basename)

I have a lit of files (which I get from `find bla -name "*.so"`) such as:

`/bla/a1.so
/bla/a2.so
/bla/blo/a3.so
/bla/blo/a4.so
/bla/blo/bli/a5.so`

and I want to rename them such as it becomes:

`/bla/liba1.so
/bla/liba2.so
/bla/blo/liba3.so
/bla/blo/liba4.so
/bla/blo/bli/liba5.so`

... i.e. add the prefix 'lib' to the basename

any idea on how to do that in bash ?

Comment: It's not a duplicate... the other question is asking how to to this with Make whereas this is asking how to achieve the same thing but directly in a bash script

Comment: Voting to reopen, not dupe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
for a in /bla/a1.so /bla/a2.so /bla/blo/a4.so
do
  dn=$(dirname $a)
  fn=$(basename $a)
  mv "$a" "${dn}/lib${fn}"
done
```

should do it. You might want to add code to read the list of filenames from a file, rather than listing them verbatim in the script, of course.

Comment: Thanks to (I guess) Aaron for adding quotes, that's a good point.

Comment: yes of course, I forgot about dirname so I couldn't see how to split path easily... thanks ! altough the last line should:   mv $a $dn/lib$fn otherwise, bash will think of dn and fn as shell commands

Comment: +1 for using `$()` instead of backticks.

Answer (score 6):

```
find . -name "*.so" -printf "mv '%h/%f' '%h/lib%f'\n" | bash
```

The code will rename files in current directory and subdirectories to append "lib" in front of .so filenames.

No looping needed, as `find` already does its recursive work to list the files. The code builds the "mv" commands one by one and executes them. To see the "mv" commands without executing them, simply remove the piping to shell part "| bash".

`find`'s printf command understands many variables which makes it pretty scalable. I only needed to use two here:

- %h: directory
- %f: filename

**How to test it**:

Run this first (will perform nothing yet, only print lines on the screen):

```
find . -name "*.so" -printf "mv '%h/%f' '%h/lib%f'\n" | less -S
```

This will show you all the commands that your script will execute. If you're satisfied with the result, simply execute it afterwards by piping it into `bash` instead of `less`.

```
find . -name "*.so" -printf "mv '%h/%f' '%h/lib%f'\n" | bash
```

Comment: You might want to add an appropriate `mindepth` and `maxdepth` to the find command and protect the file and directory names with quotes in case they [shudder] have spaces in them. `find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name "*.so" -printf "mv '%h/%f' '%h/lib%f'\n" | sh`

Comment: I agree for the quotes, i've updated my code in consequence.

Comment: Does this solution have any problems with many results? eg. hitting max command length or anything like that?

Comment: No because it would print it line by line. I've updated my answer to give a way to test it in a dry run.

Answer (score 2):

**`while` multiliner**

A slightly more robust and generalized solution based on $nfm (maybe more than you really need) would be

```
while IFS= read -r -u3 -d $'\0' FILE; do
    DIR=`dirname $FILE`;
    FILENAME=`basename $FILE`;
    mv $FILE ${DIR}/lib${FILENAME};
done 3< <(find bla -name *.so -print0 | sort -rz)
```

This is quite robust:

- read -u3 and 3< does not interfere with stdin
- -print0 + IFS= + -d $'/0' allows for newlines in filenames
- sort -rz renames deeper paths first, so that you can even rename directories and the files inside them at once

**`find -execdir` + `rename`**

This would be perfect if it weren't for the PATH annoyances, see: [Find multiple files and rename them in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux/54163971#54163971)

Answer (score 1):

Try `mmv`:

```
cd /bla/
mmv "*.so" "lib#1.so"
```

(`mmv "*" "lib#1"` would also work but it's less safe).

If you don't have `mmv` installed, get it.

Comment: mmv sounds powerful ! thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

basename and dirname are your friends :)

You want something like this (excuse my bash syntax - it's a little rusty):

```
for FILE in `find bla -name *.so` do
    DIR=`dirname $FILE`;
    FILENAME=`basename $FILE`;
    mv $FILE ${DIR}/lib${FILENAME};
done
```

Beaten to the punch!

Answer (score 0):

Note I've commented out the mv command to prevent any accidental mayhem

```
for f in *
do
    dir=`dirname "$f"`
    fname=`basename "$f"`
    new="$dir/lib$fname"
    echo "new name is $new"
    # only uncomment this if you know what you are doing
    # mv "$f" "$new" 
done
```