# makefile: how to add a prefix to the basename?

Tags: makefile, prefix

I have a list of file path like that:

```
FILE_PATH := a1.so a2.so bla/a3.so bla/a3.so bla/blo/a4.so....
```

I need to add a prefix to the basename in order to get:

```
FILE_PATH_PREFIXED := liba1.so liba2.so bla/liba3.so bla/liba3.so bla/blo/liba4.so....
```

any idea?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Look at Make's `addsuffix` function.

```
Here is an example we use with `addsuffix` to place obj files one directory below
the source.


SOURCE += MainThread.cpp
SOURCE += Blah.cpp

OBJ=$(join $(addsuffix ../obj/, $(dir $(SOURCE))), $(notdir $(SOURCE:.cpp=.o)))
```

From the make [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html):

> `$(addprefix prefix,names...)`
>
> The argument names is regarded as a series of names, separated by
> whitespace;  prefix is used as a unit. The value of prefix is
> prepended to the front of each  individual name and the resulting
> larger names are concatenated with single  spaces between them. For
> example,
>
> ```
> $(addprefix src/,foo bar)
> ```
>
> produces the result `src/foo src/bar`.

Comment: ah thanks ! I knew about the addprefix/addsuffix functions but I was missing the join function...

Comment: I agree with dm76' assesment that indeed the key value of this fine answer is join().