# Regex to rename all files recursively removing everything after the character "?" commandline

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line

I have a series of files that I would like to clean up using commandline tools available on a *nix system. The existing files are named like so.

```
filecopy2.txt?filename=3
filecopy4.txt?filename=33
filecopy6.txt?filename=198
filecopy8.txt?filename=188
filecopy3.txt?filename=19
filecopy5.txt?filename=1
filecopy7.txt?filename=5555
```

I would like them to be renamed removing all characters after and including the "?".

```
filecopy2.txt
filecopy4.txt
filecopy6.txt
filecopy8.txt
filecopy3.txt
filecopy5.txt
filecopy7.txt
```

I believe the following regex will grab the bit I want to remove from the name,

```
\?(.*)
```

I just can't figure out how to accomplish this task beyond this.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression to solve this problem.

Comment: `find -execdir` + `rename` is almost nirvana: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux/54163971#54163971

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -depth -name '*[?]*' -exec sh -c 'for i do
  mv "$i" "${i%[?]*}"; done' sh {} +
```

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(**/)(*)\?*'  '$1$2'
```

Change it to:

```
zmv -Q '(**/)(*)\?*(D)' '$1$2'
```

if you want to rename dot files as well.

Note that if filenames may contain more than one `?` character, both will only trim from the rightmost one.

Comment: That's awfully convoluted and complex. Look at @GoZoner's answer

Comment: @JimGarrison: GoZoner's answer ignores the `"recursively"` requirement.

Comment: @sch your first one is great and worked without installing any additional software. Thanks

Comment: +1. Why `-depth` instead of `-type f`? Is it correct: the second `sh` is to avoid losing the first filename in every batch due to `for i do`  receives `"$@"` that doesn't include the first arg (it is usually a program name in other context).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, `-type f` is for regular files only. The OP didn't say he didn't want the fifo, symlink, directory, door, socket and other types of files renamed. Without `-depth`, you'd run into problems if directories had to be renamed. Yes, you're correct about `"$@"` starting at `$1` and `$0` receiving that `sh`.

Answer (score 3):

A bash command:

```
for file in *; do
  mv $file ${file%%\?filename=*}
done
```

Comment: You could simplify to `\?*`.

Comment: You're missing a `--` and quotes around the variables. Note that it will omit dotfiles.

Comment: No I'm not.  Besides, the point is to illustrate `${var%%pattern}`

Comment: Then mention that your solution assumes that filenames don't contain space or tab or newline character don't start with `-`. What we know though is that they do contain wildcard characters which could be expanded (for instance, try it in a directory that contains `file?x`, `file-x` and `file.x`.

Answer (score 3):

If all files are in the same directory (ignoring `.dotfiles`):

```
$ rename -n 's/\?filename=\d+$//' -- *
```

If you want to rename files recursively in a directory hierarchy:

```
$ find . -type f -exec rename -n 's/\?filename=\d+$//' {} +
```

Remove `-n` option, to do the renaming.

Comment: Note that it assumes the `perl` implementation of `rename`, not the one that comes with `util-linux`.

Comment: @sch: yes. Though `update-alternatives --list rename` (Ubuntu) shows the only choice: `/usr/bin/prename`. And `apt-file search $(readlink -f $(which rename))` confirms that indeed `prename` from `perl` package is used.

Comment: They are completely incompatible, so making them _alternatives_ wouldn't make sense. They used to be though (see [Debian bug #439935](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=439935)). The util-linux `rename` is called `rename.ul` on Debian and its derivatives, but other distributions (I beleive Fedora to be amongst them) have the util-linux `rename` as the default `rename`.

Answer (score 1):

I this case you can use the *cut* command:

```
echo 'filecopy2.txt?filename=3' | cut -d? -f1
```

example:

```
find . -type f -name "*\?*" -exec sh -c 'mv $1 $(echo $1 | cut -d\? -f1)' mv {}  \;
```

You can use *rename* if you have it:

```
rename 's/\?.*$//' *
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this after downloading a bunch of files where the URL included parameters and those parameters ended up in the file name.

This is a Bash script.

```
for file in *; do
  mv $file ${file%%\?*};
done
```