# rename multiple files with regular-expression

Tags: bash

Inside a folder I have a file structure, the files have all a name whose format

name`-randomstring`.extension

eg

```
./dir1/aaa-5h34jk5hk.js
./dir2/bbb-5yh45uh9h.css
./dir3/ccc-uiero6tio.js
./dir3/ddd-7y8fygfre.css
. . .
```

with a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script I would like to **rename** them recursively; so to eliminate the `-randomstring` from every file

```
./dir1/aaa.js
./dir2/bbb.css
./dir3/ccc.js
./dir3/ddd.css
. . .
```

Comment: @Tom: It's no duplicate. The link should only show that it is possible to use sed's syntax with rename command.

Comment: You mean because the file pattern is not exactly the same, it's not a duplicate? I disagree.

Comment: Do you have the other directories inside that directory? I mean do you need renaming recursively?

Comment: yes need renaming recursively, with find command and piping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16541582/2088135 in that case.

Comment: @Tom thanks, this question helps me to set the recursive command with "find", but how to rename the single file?
$ find . -exec rename  ?????   '{}' \;

Comment: Do you have access to **Perl**?

Answer (score 0):

if you do not mind using **Perl** then you can do anything you like.

for example for renaming all files with this structure:

```
dir > find .
.
./00_file.txt
./01_file.txt
./02_file.txt
./dir1
./dir1/00_file.txt
./dir1/01_file.txt
./dir1/02_file.txt
./dir2
./dir2/00_file.txt
./dir2/01_file.txt
./dir2/02_file.txt
./dir3
./dir3/00_file.txt
./dir3/01_file.txt
./dir3/02_file.txt   
./find.log
```

then save your list in a file like: `find.log` now you can use **Perl**

```
dir > perl -lne '-f && ($old=$_) && s/file/ABCD/g && print "$old => $_"' find.log
./00_file.txt => ./00_ABCD.txt
./01_file.txt => ./01_ABCD.txt
./02_file.txt => ./02_ABCD.txt
./dir1/00_file.txt => ./dir1/00_ABCD.txt
./dir1/01_file.txt => ./dir1/01_ABCD.txt
./dir1/02_file.txt => ./dir1/02_ABCD.txt
./dir2/00_file.txt => ./dir2/00_ABCD.txt
./dir2/01_file.txt => ./dir2/01_ABCD.txt
./dir2/02_file.txt => ./dir2/02_ABCD.txt
./dir3/00_file.txt => ./dir3/00_ABCD.txt
./dir3/01_file.txt => ./dir3/01_ABCD.txt
./dir3/02_file.txt => ./dir3/02_ABCD.txt
```

**how it works?**

1. read the file
2. let only file; not directory or other stuffs with: `-f`
3. then save the old name: `($old=$_)`
4. then doing substitution with: `s///g` operator
5. finally rename the old file to new one that is `$_`

**NOTE** I used `print` and you should use `rename` like this:

```
dir > perl -lne '-f && ($old=$_) && s/file/ABCD/g && rename $old, $_' find.log
dir > find .
.
./00_ABCD.txt
./01_ABCD.txt
./02_ABCD.txt
./dir1
./dir1/00_ABCD.txt
./dir1/01_ABCD.txt
./dir1/02_ABCD.txt
./dir2
./dir2/00_ABCD.txt
./dir2/01_ABCD.txt
./dir2/02_ABCD.txt
./dir3
./dir3/00_ABCD.txt
./dir3/01_ABCD.txt
./dir3/02_ABCD.txt
./find.log
```

---

**NOTE** Since the `find` returns list of all files and sub-directories, with this technique Perl **renames** all the files! Thus first use `print` then `rename`. And your pattern can be: `-.*(?=\.)`. In fact:

```
s/-.*(?=\.)//g
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a native bash loop:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable ** for recursive expansion
for file in **/*{j,cs}; do
    # remove everything up to the last . to get extension
    ext=${file##*.}

    # remove everything after the last - and concat with extension
    new_name=${file%-*}$ext 

    # -- prevents weird filenames being interpreted as options
    mv -- "$file" "$new_name" 
done
shopt -u globstar # disable ** if you don't want it anymore e.g. in a script
```