# Rename all files of a certain name within all second-level sub-directories

Tags: bash, loops, rename, quotes, mv

My goal is to automate the following process: search within all second-level sub-directories, and for all files called "Test.pptx" in said sub-directories, rename to "Test - Appended.pptx". Based on responses I have seen to other questions on StackOverflow I have attempted the following code:

```
for D in *; do
        if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
                echo "${D}"
                for E in "${D}"; do
                        if [ -d "${E} ]; then
                                echo "${E}"
                                for f in "Test.pptx"; do mv "$f" "Test - Appended.pptx"; done
                        fi
                done
        fi
done
```

I set the script executable (using `chmod +x`) and run it, but get the following errors:

```
line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I am a relative newcomer to Bash scripts, so I would appreciate any help in diagnosing the errors and achieving the initial goal. Thank you!

Comment: Please add a shebang and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find multiple files and rename them in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `find`:

```
while read -r pptx
do
    mv -n "${pptx}" "${pptx%.pptx} - Appended.pptx"
done < <( find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "*.pptx" )
```

Be aware, that I did not test it and it might need adaptions on your special case.
As long as the `-n` option is set in `mv` it will not overwrite anything.

Answer (score 0):

sub-loops not really needed.

```
for f in */*/Test.pptx; do mv "$f" "${f%/*}/Test - Appended.pptx"; done
```

`${f%/*}` is the current file's full path with everything from the last slash (`/`) forward stripped off, so if the file is `a/b/Test.pptx` then `${f%/*}` is `a/b`.